# What does the backslash denote in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I believe this draws from set theory but my question is:

What does the backslash denote in probability theory?

For example: what does a \ b denote?

In an application of a probability problem you could be given an arbitrary probability like:

P ( a \ b) = .50 or 50%

What would this effectively mean? How could you use this information then to determine the probabilities for two independent events P(A) and P(B)?

Comment: Do you mean $P(A|B)$ or $P(A\B)$? Give us more context, because the latter is the set minus and the former arises in conditional probability.

Comment: In terms of elementary set theory (*which probability theory is built upon*) $A\setminus B=\{x~:~x\in A,x\notin B\}$ is [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) so $Pr(A\setminus B)$ is the probability of $A$ happening while $B$ does not happen.  Meanwhile $Pr(A\mid B)$ represents the [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) of $A$ occurring given prior knowledge that $B$ occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash denotes the "relative complement" or "set difference". The set $A \setminus B$ consists of all those elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$. In a probability $P(A \setminus B)$, it means "the probability that event $A$ occurs but event $B$ does not occur". If $A, B$ are independent, then
$$
P(A \setminus B) = P(A \cap B^c) = P(A)P(B^c) = P(A)(1- P(B)),
$$
but this is not enough to determine $P(A)$ or $P(B)$ by itself.

Comment: If you have say P(A) = 2P(B) is this sufficient information to solve for the probabilities?

Comment: @Ethan, why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Sorry I realize that was a dumb question, with an arbitrary probability for a \ b it is easy to solve, otherwise you cannot.